# TexPad Mac Os X - %force-texpad-dependency

Tags: animate, texpad, dependencies

I am facing a puzzling problem.
I am working with TexPad 1.8.12 on Mac OS X 10.15.4.
I compile with pdflatex in the cloud, but have also experienced the issue with the local custom Texpad texlive distribution.

In a beamer presentation, I am preparing I use the animate package.
I have the following frame in the presentation.

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Without strong convexity \& smoothness...}
  \begin{center}
    %\includegraphics{graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-2.pdf}
    \animategraphics[loop,autoplay]{15}{graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-}{0}{2}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

With the above code, I obtain the error

```
Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.pdf',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.mps',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.png',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.jpg',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.jpeg',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.jp2',
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.j2k' or
(animate)                `graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.jpx',
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.
```

However, the file paths are correct and the files exist. If I comment out `\animategraphics` and comment in `\includegraphics`, the presentation compiles correctly.

Moreover, after having included each file (slides-0.pdf, slides-1.pdf, slides-2.pdf) at least once and compiling, I can comment out `\includegraphics` and comment in `\animategraphics` again. It all compiles correctly then, but after closing TexPad, I need to do it again.

Why does TexPad find the files with `\includegraphics` but not with `\animategraphics`?
How do I make it work with `\animategraphics`?

EDIT: I can fix the issue with with %force-texpad-dependency
However, I do not want to manually force-texpad-dependency for every single file. What is the most elegant solution, how do I force-texpad-dependency of an entire directory?

Comment: I would ask the texpad support.

Comment: Thanks, will try and post the answer here.

Comment: Did you test, whether `\includegraphics{graphics/animations/gradient_descent_toofast/slides-0.pdf}` works as well? (The error message is about this file.)

Comment: Yes, I did. As I said in the question, the problem is not the filepaths. The problem occurs when compiling with TexPad in the cloud. TexPad is supposed to send all dependent files to the cloud. For this it has a custom parser that scans through your source to pick up all files. But they failed to add support for the animate package and therefore these files are not sent to the cloud. If you includegraphics first, then they are sent, because TexPad picks up includegraphics. The current fix is to manually force dependency. In the future they hopefully add support for animate.